# mysql process won't die on mac

Tags: macos, mysql

I have a problem in the setup of mysql using homebrew and so I decided to uninstall and start with a clean slate. Following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20983018/3540782) I try to kill the process by

1. Getting the process id through: `ps -ax | grep mysql`
2. Using `kill -9 PID` to kill the process

My problem is that the PID keeps changing, even if I didn't run the kill command. As an example, here's the result from running `ps -ax | grep mysql` 3 times consecutively:

```
➜  ~ ps -ax | grep mysql@5.7          
 7251 ttys000    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox mysql@5.7
➜  ~ ps -ax | grep mysql@5.7
 7257 ttys000    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox mysql@5.7
➜  ~ ps -ax | grep mysql@5.7
 7263 ttys000    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox mysql@5.7
```

Among the million things I tried, I

1. `launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/**file_name_containing_mysql**` and then deleted this file altogether
2. Another suggestion I found online was running `sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist` (in my case this is the only process under LaunchDaemons that had mysql in it). The result was:

> /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist: Could not
> find specified service Unload failed: 113: Could not find specified
> service

One interesting thing also was a suggestion to stop the service of brew using sudo. Tried this as well:

```
sudo brew services stop mysql@5.7
Stopping `mysql@5.7`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mysql@5.7` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7)
```

The magical thing is that I got this **AFTER UNINSTALLING MYSQL@5.7**. Yeah you read this right.

And after all this, running `ps -ax | grep mysql` still shows mysql process running.

So in short what I'm trying to do is, kill all mysql processes. What have I not done that kill this for good?

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the answer to this here, in case someone falls upon this and learns a lesson that would save some precious hours.

```
➜  ~ ps -ax | grep mysql@5.7          
 7251 ttys000    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox mysql@5.7
```

The result of this ps, is not actually a process. It probably is the process of grepping but nothing more. I spent so much time trying to kill something that was already dead. But what do you say, learning never comes easy!

Answer (score 0):

Running -> stop brew mysql service + uninstall mysql works for me. The mysql version I wish to remove was v5.7.

```
brew services stop mysql@5.7
brew uninstall --force mysql
```